# Vue.js multiple search with checkboxes

Tags: vue.js, search, checkbox

I'm trying to create a search form with input text fields and checkboxes.
Right now I have the search working for text fields but I can't make it work for checkboxes.
I'm totally new with vue.js so probably I'm missing some basic stuff.

The problem is in the computed part in the last filter, with the categories checkboxes:

```
computed: {
filteredExperiences() {
    return this.experiences.filter( item => {
        return (
            item.destination.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchDestinations.toLowerCase()) > -1 
            && item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchExperiences.toLowerCase()) > -1 
            && item.categories.map(cat => cat.title.toLowerCase()).indexOf(this.checkedCategories.toLowerCase()) > -1 
        ) 
    })
}
```

}

So searchDestinations and searchExperiences work fine but search by categories doesn't.

Any idea why? What am I doing wrong?

This is the full code:

```
var app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    destinations: [{
            title: 'Madrid',
            slug: 'madrid'
        },
        {
            title: 'London',
            slug: 'london'
        },
        {
            title: 'Chicago',
            slug: 'chicago'
        },
        {
            title: 'Los Angeles',
            slug: 'los-angeles'
        }
    ],
    categories: [{
            title: 'Concerts',
            slug: 'concerts'
        },
        {
            title: 'Museums',
            slug: 'museums'
        },
        {
            title: 'Theaters',
            slug: 'theaters'
        },
        {
            title: 'Cinemas',
            slug: 'cinemas'
        }
    ],
    experiences: [{
            id: 1,
            title: 'Bruce Springsteen Live Madrid',
            destination: 'Madrid',
            categories: ['concerts', 'theaters'],
            duration: '2h'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: 'Mulan 2 the movie',
            destination: 'London',
            categories: ['cinemas', 'theaters'],
            duration: '2h'
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            title: 'British Museum',
            destination: 'London',
            categories: ['museums'],
            duration: '3h'
        }
    ],
    checkedCategories: [],
    searchDestinations: '',
    searchExperiences: ''
},
computed: {
    filteredExperiences() {
        return this.experiences.filter(item => {
            return (item.destination.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchDestinations.toLowerCase()) > -1 && item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchExperiences.toLowerCase()) > -1)
        })
    }
}
```

});

Here is the codepen:

See the Pen 
            [vue.js filtered multi-search](https://codepen.io/oterox/pen/eYJymjp) by Javier ([@oterox](https://codepen.io/oterox))
        on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is here:

```
        && item.categories.map(cat => cat.title.toLowerCase()).indexOf(this.checkedCategories.toLowerCase()) > -1
```

like this it should work:

```
computed: {
    filteredExperiences() {
           return this.experiences.filter( item => { 

              if(item.destination.indexOf(this.searchDestinations) < 0) { return false }
              if (item.title.indexOf(this.searchExperiences) < 0 ) { return false }
              let matchedCats = item.categories.filter(cat => {
                   let hasCat = this.checkedCategories.findIndex(checkCat => cat.toLowerCase() === checkCat.toLowerCase());
                   return hasCat > -1;
              })

              if(this.checkedCategories.length > 0 && matchedCats.length < 1)
              {
                return false;
              }
            return true;
           
    })
 }
}
```

Comment: I can't make it work, I don't know how to put it. I've copied your solution after the && with no sucess

Comment: Just a minute, I'll improve my answer

Comment: @Oterox I refactored the code to make it cleared. Please note I remove the .toLowerCase() to have a more clean code. Feel free to add it. Let me know if you still have problems.

Comment: I've applied the changes but still doesn't work. You can take a look at codepen: https://codepen.io/oterox/pen/eYJymjp it will be easier to check ;)

Comment: Got it!!! Item cats do not have a title, they are just strings. I've updated my answer after testing positive on the pen.